# Apache DocumentRoot folder encrypted with EFS

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-8.1, encrypting-file-system

As per this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575709/newly-added-files-getting-permissions-error Apache 2.2 is not supposed to be able to access its DocumentRoot if the folder has been encrypted with EFS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System

However I was wondering if there is a way, maybe by modifying the permissions for that folder, that Apache can have access to it. The OS is Windows 8.1 Professional.

The reason is that this is a non-production machine (it is used for development) which is relatively vulnerable to theft and the source code is valuable so I want it to be protected in case of physical access to the disk by unauthorised people.

Comment: Better approach would seem to be full disk encryption.  I can't imagine trying to combine EFS and Apache's document root in a professional systems administration capacity... unless, perhaps, I was looking to drive one of my coworkers insane.

Comment: Hey HoplessN00b your comment makes a lot of sense but I just wanted to figure out if there was a quick and dirty solution which does not require BitLocker and a TPM chip.

Comment: You can use BitLocker without a TPM chip. You then have to enter a passphrase every time you boot the system.

Comment: Good point. I was reading an outdated BitLocker guide which only mentioned the TPM or the USB-stored key, but now I have found out in  the Windows 8 documentation that alternatively you can also type a password at boot. Reference http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/protect-files-bitlocker-drive-encryption#1TC=windows-8